# Filebeat cannot connect to Logstash because certificate does not contain any IP SANs

Tags: ssl, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have generated SSL certificates for Filebeat (v6.1.0, ELK 5.6.4) and deployed them to the client and configured Filebeat to use the `ssl.certificate_authorities` in `filebeat.yml`. However, filebeat cannot validate the SSL certificate even though I have specified the `subjectAlternateName` in `[ v3_ca ]` in the SSL configuration.

**Generate the key:**

```
$ sudo openssl req -config cert.cnf -x509 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

**cert.cnf**

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = BL
stateOrProvinceName = blah
localityName = blah
commonName = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName = IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Why am I still getting the following error?

```
ERR  Failed to connect: x509: cannot validate certificate for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Comment: You should better specify type of entry and value, i.e. not just the IP address but `subjectAltName = IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: @jww Extremely helpful links. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the `subjectAltName` with the correct IP address and you are still seeing this error, verify that the certificate is actually picking up this property from the config file.

**Verify the key:**

```
$ openssl x509 -in certs/logstash-forwarder.crt -text -noout
```

Look for a section

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            IP Address:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If that section is missing, then for some reason the `subjectAlternateName` is not being generated for your key. In this instance, although all documents say to place the `subjectAlternateName` under the `[ v3_ca ]` section, this section won't be read unless specified (if you are using the default `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` this *might* not be a problem). For a CA: in the `certs.cnf` make sure the `[ req ]` section points the `x509_extensions` to `v3_ca`. For a CSR: in the `certs.cnf` make sure the `[ req ]` section points the `req_extensions` to `v3_ca`.

**cert.cnf**

```
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_ca  # <----------- This one, if generating a CSR
x509_extensions = v3_ca  # <---------- This one, if generating a CA

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = BL
stateOrProvinceName = blah
localityName = blah
commonName = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName = IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Regenerate the key, verify, you should see the following section in the output:

```
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
        IP Address:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Deploy and enjoy.